# Sort grep output based on the content inside file

Tags: bash

I have markdown files inside a directory with each file having a tag,  created date, and modified date. I have to combine the markdown files with a unique tag. But I also have to combine files sorted by the created date.

```
tags: [Notebooks, Notebooks/Django]
title: Django - Python Web Framework
created: '2019-07-19T15:33:21.917Z'
modified: '2019-07-19T15:33:53.588Z'
```

I am able to filter files based on the required tag (given as command argument to the script) using grep (rg) and combine them. But how do I sort them based on created date and write to a single file?

```sh
IFS='
'
variable=$(rg -l Notebooks/$1)

for i in $variable; do
        cat $i >> ./Scripts/$1.md
done
```

variable should contain list files sorted based on created date on each markdown file

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep again to extract the created date, and then sort on the output of grep, and finally cut the filename back out:

```
variable_sorted=$(grep -H created $variable | sort -k 2 | cut -f1 -d:)
```

Assumption: your created date is always in the same format, so that sorting on the string gives you the result you want.